# Problema al crear registro de usuarios en Android Studio 3.5.1

Tags: java, android

Estoy haciendo un tutorial para diseñar un registro de usuarios en Android, ya que no tengo experiencia previa programando en Android. Tengo el código exactamente igual que en el tutorial en el activity_main.xml, como adjunto a continuación. Pero el resultado en la Preview es la aplicación completamente en blanco y no entiendo qué error puede que se está produciendo. Creo que es un problema de la versión de Android Studio, ¿puede ser que sea eso?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:paddingBottom="16dp"
  android:paddingLeft="16dp"
  android:paddingRight="16dp"
  android:paddingTop="16dp"
  android:paddingEnd="16dp"
  tools:context=".MainActivity">

  <LinearLayout
      android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
      android:layout_centerVertical="true"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">


      <EditText
         android:layout_margin="15dp"
         android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
         android:id="@+id/editTextEmail"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:hint="Enter your email"
         ></EditText>

     <EditText
         android:layout_margin="15dp"
         android:id="@+id/editTextPassword"
         android:inputType="textPassword"
         android:hint="Enter your password"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         ></EditText>

     <Button
         android:layout_margin="15dp"
         android:id="@+id/buttonRegister"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="Register user"
         ></Button>

   </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Buenas @Montu según probé  tu .xml, no estaría mostrando nada debido a la definición de la anchura del `LinearLayout` la cual la tienes `android:layout_width="0dp"`, prueba cambiándola a `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` para visualizar los componentes en la misma

Comment: Como dice el comentario anterior, el problema está en que no le estas asignando un ancho al LinearLayout por ende te aparece vacía la Preview